# VBA read pdf and set bookmarks value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have this code, and I want to read the PDF and extract bookmarks with their set values.

```
Private Sub Btn_Cerfa_Click()
    Dim avDoc As Object
    Dim pdDoc As Object
    Dim bookmarks As Object
    Dim bookmark As Object
    
    Dim stFile As String
    Dim app As Object
    
    ' Chemin vers le fichier PDF
    stFile = "C:\MODELES\signet.pdf"
    
  
    
    ' Ouvrir le document PDF
    Set avDoc = CreateObject("PDFXEdit.PXVControl.6")
    If avDoc.Open(stFile, "") Then
        Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc
        Set bookmarks = pdDoc.GetBookmarks
        
        ' Parcourir et manipuler les signets
        For Each bookmark In bookmarks
            If bookmark.title = "date" Then
                ' Assumer que la mï¿½thode SetValue existe (hypothï¿½tique)
                bookmark.setValue "jjjj"
            ElseIf bookmark.title = "serv" Then
                ' Assumer que la mï¿½thode SetValue existe (hypothï¿½tique)
                bookmark.setValue "hhh"
            End If
            ' Vous devrez utiliser les mï¿½thodes rï¿½elles de manipulation de signets ici
        Next bookmark
        
        ' Enregistrer les modifications
        pdDoc.Save 1, "C:\MODELES\signet.pdf"
        
        ' Fermer le document
        pdDoc.Close
    End If
    
    ' Fermer Acrobat
    avDoc.Close True
    
    ' Libï¿½rer les objets
    Set app = Nothing
    Set avDoc = Nothing
    Set pdDoc = Nothing
    Set bookmarks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What happens when you execute your code? And which library is `PDFXEdit.PXVControl.6` using?

Comment: erreur d'execution 429 / un composant activeX ne peut pas vréer l'objet , sinon la bibliothèque c'est pour mon application pdf (pdf xchange viexer)

Comment: Execution error 429 / An ActiveX component cannot create the object," otherwise the library is for my PDF application (PDF-XChange Viewer).